# Why is compiling this code producing an error?

Tags: c++, gcc, aix

I believe this is the right header:

```
  #include <cstdio>
```

Note, there is a difference between the above declaration and this one:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
```

The first one puts everything in the "std" namespace, the 2nd one doesn't. So I am using the first one.

Below is the code which I am compiling using g++4.4.6 on aix6.1:-

```
#include <cstdarg> //< va_list
#include <cstdio>  //< vsnprintf()
#include "virtual_utils.h"

namespace VS
{


const char* format_str( const char* str, ... ) throw()
{
  static char buf[10][1024];
  static unsigned long buf_no = 0;

  char* cur_buf = buf[ ++buf_no % 10 ];
  buf_no %= 10;

  va_list vl;
  va_start( vl, str );
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  std::_vsnprintf( cur_buf, sizeof(buf), str, vl );
#else
  std::vsnprintf( cur_buf, sizeof(buf), str, vl );
#endif

  return cur_buf;
}


} //< namespace VS
```

These are the following errors which I am getting:-

```
virtual_utils.C: In function 'const char* VS::format_str(const char*, ...)':
virtual_utils.C:28: error: 'vsnprintf' is not a member of 'std'
```

---

**Edit:**
Modifying the above code to remove the `#include "virtual_utils.h"` and to add a `main()`, it [compiles with a warning under gcc4.3.4 on Ideone](http://ideone.com/fZ1fX) and [cleanly under gcc4.5.1](http://ideone.com/X23mS).

Comment: And you're certain _MSC_VER isn't defined anywhere ?

Comment: @nos It is vsnprintf instead of _vsnprintf and _MSC_VER is not defined anywhere.

Comment: `std::vsnprintf` is in `<cstdarg>`, not `<cstdio>`

Comment: @CharlesB : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/ I didn't find it. Check again.

Comment: [This compiles (albeit with a warning) fine for me](http://ideone.com/fZ1fX) under gcc4.3.4 and [without the warning under gcc4.5.1](http://ideone.com/X23mS)

Comment: @crazy_prog What's in the virtual_utils.h header?

Comment: @razlebe : Did u compile on aix? If yes, which version? and How did you compile without virtual_utils.h?

Comment: @crazy_prog: you're right (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdio.h.html)

Comment: @crazy I only compiled using ideone - I have no idea which OS they're hosting their compiler on I'm afraid. Why not take the edited code in its entirety from one of those links and see if it builds? It may give us a clue as to whether there's an issue elsewhere in your program.

Comment: @razlebe : It is showing the same error.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Not only type-unsafe, but invoking undefined behaviour for non-POD types.

Comment: @crazy In that case, I wonder whether it is something specific to your compiler version/OS combination. Would be handy if someone else could replicate this on aix/g++4.4.6

Comment: It would be great if somebody replicates the same in some other aix6.1/g++ combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile with `--save-temps`, and examine the `.ii` file it produces. That should make it clear what's defined in what namespace, and what isn't.

Comment: error is known -- "virtual_utils.C:28: error: 'vsnprintf' is not a member of 'std'".

Comment: The error is known, the cause isn't, the solution isn't. This will show you what the compiler sees, and you can learn from that what to do about it.

Comment: We know that vsnprintf is not a member of std. It compiles fine with gcc-4.0.2/aix? What can we do now?

Comment: [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio) suggests `cstdio` shouldn't define `vnsprintf`. GCC 4.0.2 was probably broken and has been fixed, although I don't have a standard handy to confirm that. You can either use stdio.h, or write your code a different way.